# Read first X bytes of input stream in Scala

Tags: scala, io

What is the most compact and scala-like way to read the first X bytes of an input stream to a buffer?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'm curious because unless you are interacting with something that uses a block-based protocol or file structure, it seems improbable that this would be useful.

Comment: And what should happen if fewer than X bytes remain to be read?

Comment: The pattern in java is to do continual reads until you have accumulated the X bytes (or an error occurs).  There always seems to be a more compact/scala/functional way of doing things, so thats why I'm asking.

Comment: Yes but what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Are you reading from a stream divided into blocks whose size is known, or is X the length of the stream?

Comment: The nature of the data or where its coming from really doesn't matter.  I have some stream coming from some place, and I want to read a bunch of data (say 10 bytes) at the start of the stream.  Not making any assumption about the stream.

Comment: So it should not assume that the stream has even 10 bytes. So it should do what if it encounters such a stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your `java.io.InputStream` in a [`scala.io.BufferedSource`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.BufferedSource) to get access the usual iterator operations:

```
val bufSrc = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream)
val chars = bufSrc.take(X)  // X being the number of bytes
```

Note that `BufferedSource.take` gives you an iterable of Char.

Comment: This looks good! What about if you want to work with bytes (not Chars)?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).reader.read(..)
```

There are several `read` methods to accomplish what you require

Comment: With this solution you still need a loop doing reads because you are not guaranteed to get all the bytes on the first try.

Comment: There no guarantee, because the behavior depends on the type of `InputStream` your would use.